# Is there a 100% working way to send two forms with one click in php?

Tags: php, forms, onclick

I have these two forms, and I want to send them both with one click.
The first form loads up an image into the server. The second one loads up infomation into a database. Any ideas?

Comment: Basically this is impossible with raw HTML. You will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

### You can't.

What you're trying to achieve is having two requests to the server on a single click of a button, which is not possible.

---

Work around is to use **AJAX** requests to submit these two forms one by one asynchronously, and refresh the page or do the final processing only after both the requests gets completed successfully.

Comment: You mean *You can*. Using Ajax is not a workaround, it's a proper solution.

Comment: OP was looking for a way to do it from PHP. So it's not possible with only PHP.

Comment: `onClick` suggests javascript. Although he's not very clear, I give you that ;).